# In my code I am having a dilemma with the 'Colorama' module specifically changing my line color using the input() command

Tags: python, module, colorama

Here is the code: **IM USING VISUAL STUDIO CODE BTW**

```
import requests
from colorama import Fore, Style, init
from time import sleep

init()

print(f'{Fore.RED}WELCOME TO JYSKO\'S WEBSITE CHECKER!')
print(f'{Fore.YELLOW}Add my discord: ')
print(f'{Fore.YELLOW}Jy$ko#0420')

def main():
    try:
        site = input(f'{Fore.RED}Please Enter The Website Here: ')
        response = requests.get(site)
        requests.get(site)
        while True:
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print(f'{Fore.GREEN}Online!')
                sleep(1)
            else:
                print(f'{Fore.RED}Offline!')
                sleep(1)
    except:
        print(f'{Fore.RED}Unknown Error Occured.')
main()
```

The problem is located in the function named 'Main()'.  As you can see in the previous lines of code, the last color used is '{Fore.YELLOW}' and in the input() command in this function I request the color `RED` but when executed still comes out as yellow.  I have tried most solutions available on this platform and am seeking help.
When the code is executed this is what spits out:

```
(RED TEXT->)WELCOME TO JYSKO'S WEBSITE CHECKER!
(YELLOW TEXT->)Add my discord: 
(YELLOW TEXT->)Jysko#0420
(SUPPOSE TO BE RED BUT RETURNS YELLOW->){Fore.RED}Please Enter The Website Here:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed the f-string for the input.

```
input(f'{Fore.YELLOW}...')
```

Without the 'f' at the beginning of the string, {Fore.YELLOW} is just treated as part of the string. However, with the f-string, then the contents inside the curly braces are more or less treated the same as having:

```
input(Fore.YELLOW + 'your string contents')
```

---

EDIT: Worked with OP and found a strange error with Windows. The above works on Mac and Linux, but not Windows -- There seems to be a quirk on Windows python3.8 that prevents colorama from setting the text color in input(). However there is a workaround by adding a print statement first:

```
print(Fore.RED, end='') # Changes color, but doesn't add new line
input('original text')
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work with both changes advised to me above.

Comment: Can you try this separate from the rest of your code? In a fresh python file? I tested the same thing and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Can I reach you via discord or anything else maybe in a direct message service?

Comment: Here is my tag: Jysko#0420 I'll accept your request right away!